# Android : Remove shadow on ProgressBar from Toolbar

Tags: android, xml

I have an activity with following xml structure

```
<LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <ProgressBar/>
            <FrameLayout>
                ....
                ....
            <FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As expected, the ProgressBar is having shadow from the Toolbar. I tried adding `android:elevation="1000dp"` to ProgressBar, but that doesn't remove the shadow on ProgressBar. The only thing seems to work is to add `app:elevation="0dp"` to `AppBarLayout`. But that removes the shadow of `Toolbar` on all elements even after `ProgressBar` is gone.

What I would like to have is that the `Toolbar` has same elevation as `ProgressBar` so that it doesn't cast shadow on `ProgressBar`. But the shadow of `Toolbar` on rest of the elements in `FrameLayout` should be present.